# Intervalos entre duas colunas datas

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select

O problema é o seguinte, eu tenho uma tabela que armazena as licenças (maternidade, saúde, etc...) de um funcionário, contendo as datas de inicio e fim da licença e outras informações que não são relevantes para o problema, essa tabela é usada para montar uma folha de pagamento de funcionários para gerência, e para gerar essa folha de pagamento é passado o mês de referência.

Quando informado o mês, por exemplo Setembro, o script irá fazer uma busca por ocorrências nas tabelas que estejam entre as datas de '2019-09-01' até '2019-09-30'. Estou tendo problemas com a consulta somente na tabela de licença dos funcionários, as demais estão sendo tratadas perfeitamente, isso ocorre porque o tempo da licença pode ser maior que qualquer outra ocorrência, vou exemplificar melhor abaixo.

Tenho uma licença que vai de 27/08 até 26/10 totalizando 60 dias. Quando for gerar a folha de pagamento referente ao mês 08, me retorna que o funcionário trabalhou 26 dias nesse mês, e referente ao mês 10 me retorna que ele trabalhou 4 dias, até aqui está ok, o que eu não estou conseguindo é tratar o mês de Setembro, eu consigo tratar os extremos mas não consigo tratar o que está entre essas duas datas, em Setembro ele me retorna 30 dias, o correto seria 0 dias, pois o funcionário não trabalhou em Setembro. O mesmo vale para uma licença de 09/05 a 05/09 eu consigo os extremos mas não o que está entre, que são os meses de junho, julho e agosto.

Abaixo o script SQL, o script php é bem extenso, como foi testado direto no banco e não está me retornando o resultado esperado, acredito que o problema esteja na consulta.

tab_funcionario_licenca:

```
id | id_funcionario |     data_inicial      |      data_final
1  |        2       | '2019-08-27 00:00:00' | '2019-10-26 23:59:00'
```

Script de Consulta com o mês de Setembro

```
SELECT data_inicial, data_final FROM tab_funcionario_licenca WHERE id_funcionario = 2 AND ((data_inicial >= '2019-09-01' AND data_inicial <= '2019-09-30') OR (data_final >= '2019-09-01' AND data_final <= '2019-09-30'))
```

Resultado: Nenhum

Script de Consulta com o mês de agosto:

```
SELECT data_inicial, data_final FROM tab_funcionario_licenca WHERE id_funcionario = 2 AND ((data_inicial >= '2019-08-01' AND data_inicial <= '2019-08-31') OR (data_final >= '2019-08-01' AND data_final <= '2019-08-31'))
```

Resultado: 2019-08-27 00:00:00  até  2019-10-26 23:59:00.

O mesmo vale para o periodo de 2019-10-01 até 2019-10-31, está pegando os extremos das datas não entre elas como eu disse, isso acontece devido ao operador OR.

Agora um teste que eu fiz, modificando os operadores AND e OR, me retorna a data do funcionário, o select que foi passado foi perguntando se tem algum registro entre 01/09 e 30/09, ele me retorna a data do funcionário com isso no código PHP eu faço a diferença de dias trabalhados usando a data de referencia.. como foi passado 01/09 até 30/09, é feito o calculo da diferença entre essas datas, que retorna 30 - 30 = 0 dias trabalhados, porém o script já não funciona para as datas que estão nos extremos...

```
SELECT data_inicial, data_final FROM tab_funcionario_licenca WHERE id_funcionario = 2 AND (((data_inicial >= '2019-09-01' AND data_inicial <= '2019-09-30') AND (data_final >= '2019-09-01' AND data_final <= '2019-09-30')) OR (('2019-09-01' BETWEEN data_inicial AND data_final) AND ('2019-09-30' BETWEEN data_inicial AND data_final)))
```

RESULTADO: 2019-08-27 00:00:00  2019-10-26 23:59:00

Abaixo o Script de criação da tabela com o insert do exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE `tab_funcionario_licenca` (

  `id` int(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

  `id_funcionario` int(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

  `data_inicial` datetime NOT NULL,

  `data_final` datetime NOT NULL

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tab_funcionario_licenca` (`id`, `id_funcionario`, `data_inicial`, `data_final`) 
VALUES
(1, 2, '2019-08-27 00:00:00', '2019-10-26 23:59:00'),
(2, 5, '2019-05-09 00:00:00', '2019-09-05 23:59:00');
```

É possível uma solução numa única consulta em SQL?
Agradeço pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja se atende:

```
SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN data_inicial < '2019-09-01' THEN '2019-09-01' ELSE data_inicial END) AS inicio, 
    (CASE WHEN data_final > '2019-09-30' THEN '2019-09-30' ELSE data_final END) fim 
FROM tab_funcionario_licenca 
WHERE id_funcionario = 2 AND ((data_inicial <= '2019-09-30' AND data_final >= '2019-09-01');
```

Comment: Deu certo sim (só tive que alterar um "(" que tem a mais depois do AND). Valeu. me retorna exatamente o que eu preciso!